# Time evolution of position of a free particle with dirac delta momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

> If the initial state of a free particle is a delta function in momentum (it has a single specified momentum $k_{o}$), how does the position evolve with time?

Thoughts:

$$\Psi(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(k)e^{i(kx - \frac{\hbar k^{2}}{2m}t)} \, dk,$$ where $\phi(k)$ is determined by the initial state vector $\Psi(x,0)$. If my initial state is $\delta(k - k_{o})$, how do I find $\Psi(x,0)$? Or, does assigning $\phi(k) = \delta(k - k_{o})$ in the integral for $\Psi(x,t)$ make sense?

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of $\phi(k)$?

Comment: @BySymmetry from what I understand, the wave function of the eigenstates of a free particle aren't normalizeable, so we take a distribution of $k$ values and integrate $e^{i(kx - \frac{\hbar k^{2}}{2m}t)}$. $\phi(k)$ then plays the role of coefficients, much like in the discrete case.

So, here if I'm correct to assume that $\phi(k)$ is the dirac delta, it would just choose the wave function eigen ket with $k = k_{o}$, and evolve that with time.

Comment: @Manimatics So that's correct. The state you obtain, however, will not be normalizable.